# When rotating a line on the X axis how can I find the distance from the original orientation?

Tags: geometry

I'm currently working on creating a 3D object using CSS3 transforms. I'm running into some difficulties in understanding how to properly adjust lines when I rotate a line:

This is an example:

[This is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXBD3.jpg)

When I rotate the line with the center of the line as the origin of rotation, it changes position - i'd like to know if there's an easy way (that wouldn't just be manually measuring) to find out the **b** and **a** values. Apologies if it's glaringly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the center of the strip if $(0,0)$, $d$ the half width and $h$ the half heigth.
The upper left corner is $(-d,h)$ and the upper right is $(d,h)$.
This last corner has polar coordinates $(\sqrt{d^2+h^2}\cos\theta_0,\sqrt{d^2+h^2}\sin\theta_0)$, where $\theta_0=\arctan(h/d)$.
When rotated, this corner has coordinates $(\sqrt{d^2+h^2}\cos(\theta+\theta_0),\sqrt{d^2+h^2}\sin(\theta+\theta_0))$, where $\theta$ is the rotation angle.

So finally we have:

$$
a=-d-\sqrt{d^2+h^2}\cos(\theta+\theta_0)\\
b=h-\sqrt{d^2+h^2}\sin(\theta+\theta_0)
$$

and this, taking into account the definition of $\theta_0$, can be simplified a little bit as

$$
a=h\sin\theta-d(1+\cos\theta)\\
b=h(1-\cos\theta)-d\sin\theta
$$

Comment: @AndyB: there was a sign error in the last line, take into account.